# What would be the ADC reading of a potentiometer whose wiper fails to be in contact with the resistor?

Tags: voltage, adc, resistance, potentiometer, trimmer

This question is part of an Arduino-ESC project I am building from the software standpoint. Some essential hardware questions tend to pop up every now and then.

I noticed electrical noises in old potentiometers' readings. They seem to be best explained by considering them moments of lack of wiper-resistor contact with the ADC giving zero readings in those situations. I am not sure what I am suggesting is true, hence I m here to know. Maybe the key is whether the convertor reads resistance or voltage, which is another thing I don't know.

In the case that all different types are available in the market, then I am asking about the pots in classical joystick gimbal module.

Comment: Anything at all; the voltage is undefined. You can connect a high value resistor from the wiper to one end of the pot (usually the 0V end) to define a safe value (close to 0) if the pot fails like that.

Comment: I understand that anything could be set to mean anything, that why I added the latter part of my question, specifying the abundantly available joystick gimbal module with two 10k pots, used in xbox and ps4 controllers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on the design of the ADC and if there are any additional components, but it might not be unusual for it to read around midscale or drift to one rail or the other.

Comment: Thanks for your help.